# How to show steps of maple's dsolve

Tags: maple

I'm trying to compare my results of some ordinary differential equations against Maple result, so I'm using maple dsolve command. While it gives me the answer, Maple is not showing the steps. How can I see a step by step answer? I have googled and found some commands like ExpandSteps for calculus but it's not working with ODEs. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: For differential equations, Maple doesn't have a "show-the-steps" option.